# How to find which type of SV occurs most in a gene?

Tags: bioinformatics

I am interested in a gene. I have data of what types of structural variants occur in this gene for a patient population (n=300). This gene in total has 200 deletions, 150 duplications, 10 inversions and 3 insertions. Events can come from the same patient (e.g. patient A has 3 deletions in this gene). This gene has a significant amount of both deletions and duplications, and that there are inversions and insertions present, but not a significant amount. How would one test this in a scientific statistical way? Would a simple student t-test do the job? And should I adjust for multiple testing?

Comment: Significant versus what? Statistical tests are always about comparisons. If you found an insertion in a gene, even just 1, and there is no ambiguity in your assay (i.e., errors in sequencing), there's no need for a statistical test versus a hypothesis of zero: the number of inserts is 1, and 1 is >0.

Comment: Duplications, deletions and inversions would constitute categorical classes. Therefore you cannot use t-test for your purpose. I guess you should use χ² test. I think you will get better answers at [statistics.se]. If you want your question can be migrated there.